# When I export ipynb jupyter notebook file to pdf, using nbconvert, table doesn't fit the page

Tags: python, pdf, jupyter-notebook, pdf-generation, nbconvert

When I run the command below, it converts my notebook to a pdf file, which is great.

`jupyter nbconvert file_name.ipynb --no-input --to=pdf`

However, I have tables like this below in the cell (fits in perfectly)

[image]

pdf export doesn't fit all the columns,in to the result.

[image]

Is there a way to force the pdf export to fit the table in the page?